# Agora vs Twilio

Tags: video-conferencing, voip

We're building an app that offers 1 on 1 and group video calls. We're trying to make a decision between using [Twilio](https://twilio.com) and [Agora](https://agora.io).

It looks like a lot of organizations have taken up Agora as their primary provider of cloud communication technologies. Hike Messenger in India is a good example.

Pricing aside, I cannot find any technical / other advantages Agora might offer over Twilio. What are some good reasons to consider either?

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)